# Вывод из базы данных определенного количества

Tags: php, mysql

Мне надо вывести определенное кол-во фотографий из mysql

Вот такой скрипт у меня стоит сейчас:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photo WHERE useridphoto='$useridphoto[id]'") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error());
if($result) { // Если mysql_query вернула не пустой результат
    while ($photo = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // Получаем строки из результата
        echo "<a href='#photo?id=$useridphoto[id]' style='margin-left: 10px;'><img src='$photo[photo]' width='60' height='60' style='
        border-radius: 4px;
        moz-border-radius: 4px;
        webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        '></a>"; // и выводим их на страницу
    }
}
?>
```

**Мне надо вывести на страницу только 10 фотографий.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `SELECT * FROM photo WHERE useridphoto='$useridphoto[id]' LIMIT 0,10`;
2. `useridphoto='$useridphoto[id]'` - в БД поля лучше называть через нижнее подчеркивание (`user_id_photo`), а в коде использовать стиль [`CamelCase`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) (`$userIdPhoto`);
3. использование вывода переменных в строке уменьшает читабельность кода. Используйте лучше такой вариант: (`"src='$photo[photo]' width='60'"`) заменить на (`"src='". $photo['photo'] . "' width='60'"`);
4. поле `"photo"` в таблице `"photo"` очень не информативное. Лучше заменить на `path`;
5. я не знаю, обрабатываются у вас данные в `$useridphoto['id']` или нет, но в запрос в явном виде лучше не подставлять данные. Прочитайте про [`PreparedStatement`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/300886/php-вывод-фотографий-в-модальном-окне